# Can't get notifications to show up with notify-send in Fedora 14 with xfce4

Tags: notifications, xfce

I can't get notifications to show up with `notify-send` in Fedora 14 with xfce4.

However, they are shown when the battery is low. Any ideas why they won't show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `xfce4-notifyd` :

> Libnotify is an implementation of the Desktop Notifications Specification which provides support for GTK+ and Qt applications and is desktop independent: it is already used by many open source apps like Evolution and Pidgin.  Libnotify can be installed with the libnotify package.
>
> In order to use libnotify, you have to install a notification server.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_notifications

Check https://docs.xfce.org/apps/notifyd/start

Configuration command: `xfce4-notifyd-config`

Comment: That's some necromancy right there. I can't verify it right now. Did you test it?

Comment: Sure, I had the same problem, found this relevant question by the \\_o< \\_o< GO search engine